# Rails 3, best way to be DRY with radio button labels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, dry

Suppose for an integer field named 'favfood' we represent the radio button choices as

```
0 indicates "no favorite"
1 indicates "Wine and cheese"
2 indicates "Burger with everything"
```

On our _edit view we display the radio buttons with the friendly labels above

On the /show view and /index view (and in several other places) when we display the user preference we display the same corresponding long text.

It seems non-DRY to put literal strings next to each radio button in _edit and then provide some logic to display the SAME literal string on /show and /index etc etc etc based upon the current value.

Furthermore, we have to repeatedly use the SAME logic that says if the value=1 display "The first choice", if the value = 2 display "The second choice".

What's the "rails-way" to handle user-friendly labels for radio labels so the labels (AND their association with values of the field) are defined once ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you should do. One use Internationalization (I18n) so that your text is stored in your en.yml file and you can use the labels instead of strings:

```
# en.yml
en:
  no_favorite: 'No favorite'
  wine_and_cheese: 'Wine and Cheese'
  burger_with_everything: 'Burger with everything'

# You can then translate the labels like this
I18n.t :no_favorite
I18n.t :wine_and_cheese
I18n.t :burger_with_everything
```

The next step would be to create some kind of hash or class that stores and translates the integer values for you. A simple array solution might look like this:

```
OPTIONS = [:no_favorite, :wine_and_cheese, :burger_with_everything]
```

You could then use the options like this:

```
selected_value = 1
I18n.t OPTIONS[selected_value] # => wine_and_cheese
OPTIONS.index :wine_and_cheese # => 1
```

Furthermore, if the selected option was a model value (say User#food_preference) you could define a function for displaying that user's food preference:

```
class User
  OPTIONS = [:no_favorite, :wine_and_cheese, :burger_with_everything]

  def display_food_preference
    I18n.t OPTIONS[food_preference]
  end
end
```

Comment: that is a nifty solution very well explained THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but why not store the strings in the model. Sth like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def favfood_description
        "bla bla" if favfood == 0
    end
end
```